# Apple Swift: what does the second argument in this function mean

Tags: swift

In the following function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
```

is the second argument the result returned by calling the function `numberOfRowsInSection` with `section` as the argument? If so, where is it getting `section` from?

Comment: That's selector notation bleeding into Swift's function naming semantics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax allows to set a name for an argument that is different from the name of the local variable used to capture that arguments value.

- `numberOfRowsInSection` is the name of the parameter that you use when calling this function.
- `section` is the name of the local variable that holds the value that got passed.

So you would call this function like so:

```
Int rowCount = tableView(tableView: aTabelView, numberOfRowsInSection: 10);
```

And in that function, you would use the argument like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return section;
}
```

Comment: so it's like python's kwarg?

Comment: No I don't think so.  Swift already has keyword arguments. This syntax just give you the ability for the outward facing name and the internal variable name ot be different.

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfRowsInSection` is the argument name when calling the function. `section` is the argument name from within the function. So, for example, you would call this function as follows:

```
myObject.tableView(aView, numberOfRowsInSection:4)
```

but from within the function, you would refer to that `4` as follows:

```
let valueOfSectionArgument = section
```